# Maruku/Markdown syntax meaning "+--" "=--"

Tags: markdown, maruku

I came across some syntax in a raw Markdown file which I believe might be Maruku specific:

```
+--{.abstract}
### Abstract
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
est laborum.
=--
```

I've searched around, but I can't find any documentation for the `+--`/`=--` block. Has anyone seen this before and can point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't look too closely, it looks like a "fenced code block" with a class attribute, both of which are available under the [Markdown](http://packages.python.org/Markdown/index.html) (Python) library:

```
~~~~{.python}
# python code
~~~~
```

The above will output:

```
<pre><code class="python"># python code
</code></pre>
```

Source: http://packages.python.org/Markdown/extensions/fenced_code_blocks.html

Just guessing, but perhaps your `+--/=--` block is a syntax from a more generalized "block" implementation, i.e., something that produces a `<div>` block.